# Spring Boot: Unable to Build With Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have created a simple spring-boot application with Java 11. Generated `build.gradle` file is as follow:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'scratches'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Upon executing `gradlew build --debug` the following error occurs:

```
09:25:19.482 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.logging.progress.ProgressLoggerFactory] > Configure project :
09:25:19.482 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Configure project :' started
09:25:19.482 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: acquired lock on :
09:25:19.482 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Notify beforeEvaluate listeners of :' started
09:25:19.483 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Notify beforeEvaluate listeners of :'
09:25:19.483 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Notify beforeEvaluate listeners of :' completed
09:25:19.485 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.build-init to root project 'java-11'' started
09:25:19.486 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :init' started
09:25:19.486 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :init'
09:25:19.486 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :init' completed
09:25:19.486 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.build-init to root project 'java-11''
09:25:19.487 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.build-init to root project 'java-11'' completed
09:25:19.489 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.wrapper to root project 'java-11'' started
09:25:19.495 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :wrapper' started
09:25:19.496 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :wrapper'
09:25:19.497 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :wrapper' completed
09:25:19.497 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.wrapper to root project 'java-11''
09:25:19.497 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.wrapper to root project 'java-11'' completed
09:25:19.499 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.help-tasks to root project 'java-11'' started
09:25:19.500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :help' started
09:25:19.501 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :help'
09:25:19.501 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :help' completed
09:25:19.501 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :projects' started
09:25:19.501 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :projects'
09:25:19.501 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :projects' completed
09:25:19.501 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :tasks' started
09:25:19.502 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :tasks'
09:25:19.502 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :tasks' completed
09:25:19.502 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :properties' started
09:25:19.502 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :properties'
09:25:19.502 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :properties' completed
09:25:19.502 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :dependencyInsight' started
09:25:19.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :dependencyInsight'
09:25:19.504 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :dependencyInsight' completed
09:25:19.504 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :dependencies' started
09:25:19.504 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :dependencies'
09:25:19.504 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :dependencies' completed
09:25:19.504 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :buildEnvironment' started
09:25:19.505 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :buildEnvironment'
09:25:19.505 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :buildEnvironment' completed
09:25:19.505 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :components' started
09:25:19.505 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :components'
09:25:19.505 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :components' completed
09:25:19.505 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :model' started
09:25:19.506 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :model'
09:25:19.506 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :model' completed
09:25:19.506 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :dependentComponents' started
09:25:19.506 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Register task :dependentComponents'
09:25:19.506 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Register task :dependentComponents' completed
09:25:19.506 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.help-tasks to root project 'java-11''
09:25:19.506 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin org.gradle.help-tasks to root project 'java-11'' completed
09:25:19.507 [INFO] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Evaluating root project 'java-11' using build file 'C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\Downloads\java-11\build.gradle'.
09:25:19.507 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply script build.gradle to root project 'java-11'' started
09:25:19.514 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Creating new cache for workingDirs, path C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\Downloads\java-11\.gradle\5.2.1\vcsMetadata-1\workingDirs.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@5630d4e
09:25:19.518 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Creating new cache for md-supplier, path C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\Workspace\gradle\.gradle\caches\5.2.1\md-supplier\md-supplier.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@2e1d1d95
09:25:19.518 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Acquiring file lock for cache directory md-supplier (C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\Workspace\gradle\.gradle\caches\5.2.1\md-supplier)
09:25:19.521 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on cache directory md-supplier (C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\Workspace\gradle\.gradle\caches\5.2.1\md-supplier).
09:25:19.522 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on cache directory md-supplier (C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\Workspace\gradle\.gradle\caches\5.2.1\md-supplier).
09:25:19.540 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Creating new cache for md-rule, path C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\Workspace\gradle\.gradle\caches\5.2.1\md-rule\md-rule.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@3cf2f8b9
09:25:19.540 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Acquiring file lock for cache directory md-rule (C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\Workspace\gradle\.gradle\caches\5.2.1\md-rule)
09:25:19.543 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on cache directory md-rule (C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\Workspace\gradle\.gradle\caches\5.2.1\md-rule).
09:25:19.544 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on cache directory md-rule (C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\Workspace\gradle\.gradle\caches\5.2.1\md-rule).
09:25:19.545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.locking.LockFileReaderWriter] Lockfiles root: C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\Downloads\java-11\gradle\dependency-locks
09:25:19.546 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of detachedConfiguration1' started
09:25:19.549 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver] Resolving configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'
09:25:19.550 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.ResolvedArtifactCaches] Creating new in-memory cache for repo 'Gradle Central Plugin Repository' [da9e8315a8be71135c1df434dd1d5d54].
09:25:19.551 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting configuration unspecified:unspecified:unspecified(detachedConfiguration1).
09:25:19.552 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver] Attempting to resolve component for org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.1.3.RELEASE using repositories [Gradle Central Plugin Repository]
09:25:19.553 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin/2.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom
09:25:19.553 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin/2.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom
09:25:19.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin/2.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom' started
09:25:19.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin/2.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom
09:25:19.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Performing HTTP GET: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin/2.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom
09:25:19.557 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
09:25:19.558 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
09:25:19.558 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {s}->https://plugins.gradle.org:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 20]
09:25:19.558 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 2][route: {s}->https://plugins.gradle.org:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 1 of 20]
09:25:19.559 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {s}->https://plugins.gradle.org:443
09:25:19.560 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to plugins.gradle.org/104.18.191.9:443
09:25:19.560 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Connecting socket to plugins.gradle.org/104.18.191.9:443 with timeout 30000
09:25:19.600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
09:25:19.601 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
09:25:19.601 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Starting handshake
09:25:19.689 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-2: Shutdown connection
09:25:19.689 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Connection discarded
09:25:19.689 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection released: [id: 2][route: {s}->https://plugins.gradle.org:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 20]
09:25:19.690 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin/2.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom'
09:25:19.690 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin/2.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom' completed
09:25:19.697 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.oldresult.TransientConfigurationResultsBuilder] Flushing resolved configuration data in Binary store in C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle4127330315613912958.bin. Wrote root 2.
09:25:19.702 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of detachedConfiguration1'
09:25:19.703 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of detachedConfiguration1' completed
09:25:19.703 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Apply script build.gradle to root project 'java-11''
09:25:19.704 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply script build.gradle to root project 'java-11'' completed
09:25:19.704 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 0.197 secs
09:25:19.704 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Notify afterEvaluate listeners of :' started
09:25:19.705 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Notify afterEvaluate listeners of :'
09:25:19.705 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Notify afterEvaluate listeners of :' completed
09:25:19.705 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: released lock on :
09:25:19.705 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Configure project :'
09:25:19.705 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Configure project :' completed
09:25:19.705 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Configure build'
09:25:19.706 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Configure build' completed
09:25:19.707 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
09:25:19.707 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: released lock on root.1
09:25:19.708 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:25:19.708 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
09:25:19.708 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:25:19.708 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
09:25:19.708 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file 'C:\Users\mohdrashidi.mohdzin\Downloads\java-11\build.gradle' line: 8
09:25:19.708 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:25:19.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
09:25:19.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:
09:25:19.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:25:19.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
09:25:19.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.1.3.RELEASE')
09:25:19.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   Searched in the following repositories:
09:25:19.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]     Gradle Central Plugin Repository
09:25:19.710 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:25:19.710 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
09:25:19.710 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
09:25:19.710 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:25:19.711 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
09:25:19.711 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
09:25:19.712 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix it? I have the same problem, and mavenCentral is already added to my repos.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

to the top of `build.gradle`

Comment: Hmm I literally just pasted your file into a blank build.gradle and was able to run `gradle tasks`. Can you run it with `--debug` and post the log?

Comment: I have included the log. However it's not a full log due to character limitation. Please tell if it's insufficient.